# UnitTesting the public interface of a class when the internals are already covered?

Tags: unit-testing

I've covered the internal implementation of my class with UnitTests. Is it still useful to test my public interface now (which is one function that is little more then a chain of calls to the internal methods)?

It feels like I would be adding additional tests that test the same thing(s).

Or is testing the public interface more an integration test (even though I've stubbed my data access so it's all processed in memory) in that way that it tests whether all the UnitTested methods work well together?

Example:

```
internal bool internalCheck() {
    // complex logic that is being unit tested
}

internal void internalDoSomething() {
    // do stuff. is being unit tested
}

public void DoIt() {
    if (internalCheck()) {
        internalDoSomething();
    }
}
```

Now if I am going to add tests that test `DoIt`, I will basically end up retesting all  logic flows for `internalCheck` and assert that when it returns true, the `internalDoSomething` is being called.

Hmm I think I've figured it out:
I need to mock the class itself and check just that the correct calls are being made, pretty much ignoring real inputs/outputs. To test the public method, rather than retesting the `internalCheck`, I use a mocking framework to have `internalCheck` return what flow I want to test and then verify that the correct methods have been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you have defined your unit.  Usually the is the class, so this would still be a unit test.

Even if you have have tested the internal methods, it is still important to test the public interface, to make sure that the internal methods work together.